# How can I change the size of two rectangles in a canvas by moving an ellipse?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a canvas with two rectangles in it, side by side. I want to have an ellipse over where they meet that I can drag horizontally and have the rectangles change size to always meet under this movable elipse, just like a slider, but with shapes. I've read this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1， snapshot as below:
[image]

and so far I have a clickable, moving ellipse and two rectangles beneath it. How do I pass the changing horizontal position of the ellipse to the two rectangles so that they can resize?

Any help appreciated, C# just seems like magic to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if all you want is to get the location of the ellipse, if yes try below snippet

```
var left=Canvas.GetLeft(ellipse1);
var top=Canvas.GetTop(ellipse1);
```

To set its location and size:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse1, left+100);
ellipse1.ActualWidth= ...;
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the xaml/cs disconnect, am I trying to set <Rectangle Canvas.Left="SomeReferenceToEllispePos"> or do I need to create some cs code to inherit from some control and react to the thumb control on the ellipse?